# How do I use SMO to transfer database to new schema?

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I want to use `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` to transfer database to a new database but with a new schema.

Here is what I am doing at the moment (I played around with the options to get the behaviour I want but without any luck):

```
  var source = new Server(GetServerConnection("sa"));
  var destination = new Server(GetServerConnection("schema_user1")); 

  source.ConnectionContext.Connect();
  destination.ConnectionContext.Connect();

  var sourceDatabase = source.Databases["support"];
  var destinationDatabase = destination.Databases["schema_test"];


  var transfer = new Transfer(sourceDatabase)
  {
    CopyAllObjects = false,
    CopyAllUserDefinedDataTypes = true,
    CopyAllTables = true,
    CopyData = true,
    CopyAllStoredProcedures = true,
    PreserveDbo = false,
    PreserveLogins = false,
    DestinationServer = destination.Name,
    DestinationDatabase = destinationDatabase.Name,
    DestinationLogin = destination.ConnectionContext.Login,
    DestinationPassword = destination.ConnectionContext.Password,
    DestinationLoginSecure = false,
    Options = {ScriptSchema = false}
  };

  transfer.TransferData();
```

I get the following error:

```
The specified schema name "dbo" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.
```

This is because schema_user1 does not have permission to dbo (which I don't want it to have).

How can I transfer it to a new schema on the destination database?

Comment: You have two choices: either give schema_user1 the permissions it needs or create a new user to run this tool with and give *that* user the permissions it needs. What you're asking for right now is like saying "I want to give this person the ability to go through this locked door but don't want to give them the key."

Comment: Even if I give schema_user1 permission (or a use a user with all permission) the database gets transferred to "dbo" I want to know if it is possible to transfer it to a new schema.

Comment: Sure. In that case, specify whatever you want the schema to be as the default schema for the new user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to specify `Options.SchemaQualify = false` for the `Transfer` object (which specifies if the schema must be used in the script or not).

Then using the user in the new database it will be created in the new schema.